# How to get a relative date in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

I want to get a `Civil` date object relative to 2 days from now.
For example, if today is 28th Feb 2022, I want to add 2 days to it.

My ballerina version is

```
Ballerina 2201.0.1 (Swan Lake)
Language specification 2022R1
Update Tool 1.3.9
```

Answer (score 6):

How about something like this? You can use `time:utcAddSeconds()` function for this purpose.

```
time:Utc utc1 = check time:utcFromString("2022-02-28T10:15:30.00Z");
decimal seconds = 172800;
time:Utc utc2 = time:utcAddSeconds(utc1, seconds);
io:println(time:utcToString(utc2));
```